# JOOQ sum field value: BigDecimal to Int

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jooq

I'm using postgres with a value field that is `numeric`. JOOQ turns it into `BigDecimal`. My JOOQ query is:

```
val sumField = DSL.sum(TABLE.VALUE)
val query = dsl().select(TABLE.id.`as`("id"), sumField.`as`("sum"))
  .from(TABLE)
  .groupBy(TABLE.id)
  .fetch()
  .map{
    record -> SumById(
      id = record.get("id").toString(),
      sum = record.get("sum").toString().toInt()
    )
  }
```

where `SumById` is a data class with `id` and `sum` fields:

```
data class SumById (val id: String, val sum: Int)
```

I can get the `Int` sum by doing `.toString().toInt()`. But I was wondering if there's a better way to turn `BigDecimal` to `Int`.

**PS**

I guess this is more of a kotlin question than a JOOQ question.

Comment: What is the type returned by `record.get(String)`?

Comment: You can define your custom extension methods for "record" class. It would be nicer to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Just reuse your column referenes from earlier:

```
record -> SumById(
  id = record.get(TABLE.id.`as`("id")),
  sum = record.get(sumField.`as`("sum"))
)
```

Alternatively, you can store those in local variables as well. Another option is to use [`Record2.value1()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record2.html#value1--) and [`Record2.value2()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record2.html#value2--)

```
record -> SumById(
  id = record.value1(),
  sum = record.value2()
)
```

... as the type information is maintained by the jOOQ API across your query (up to degrees of 22, at least).

In jOOQ 3.10, you may also be able to use the new Kotlin destructuring support, where a `Record2<String, BigDecimal>` can be destructured as follows:

```
val (id, sum) = record;
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the database is postgresql and the type for `TABLE.VALUE` is `TableField<TableRecord, BigDecimal>`. That's why I'm have a hard time to convert it to `Int`.

Comment: @breezymri: Java's `BigDecimal` type has an `intValue()` method that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can create package `org.jooq.impl` in your source set, and make there your own function `sum` with Integer type:

```java
    package org.jooq.impl

    import org.jooq.AggregateFunction
    import org.jooq.Field

    public class DSLX {
        public AggregateFunction<Integer> sum(Field<Integer> field) {
            return new Function("sum", SQLDataType.INTEGER, field);
        }
    }
```

Because class `Function` has package-private constructor.
And now you do not need to convert BigDecimal